# Describe the level set $L(f,0)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : f(x,y)=0\}$ for $f(x,y) = x^2-2x-3y+y^2$.

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

> What is the level set  $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : f(x,y)=0\}$ for
>   $$f(x,y) = x^2-2x-3y+y^2$$

Comment: $x^2-2x-3y+y^2=(x-1)^2-1+(y-\tfrac{3}{2})^2-(\tfrac{3}{2})^2=(x-1)^2+(y-\tfrac{3}{2})^2-(\tfrac{13}{4})=0$ is the equation of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

The level set of $f(x,y) = x^2-2x-3y+y^2$ corresponding to the value $0$ is the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $$f(x,y) = x^2-2x-3y+y^2=0\iff(x-1)^2+(y-\frac32)^2=\frac{13}{4}$$

Thus the searched set is the circle of radius$\dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$ centered at the point $(1,\dfrac32)$.